# Unable to run code for DSP-SIFT in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

So, I got the code for DSP-SIFT from the original works of the author in the form of a toolbox. When I followed the instructions and tried to get it to run in MATLAB :

```
>> dsp_setup
>> dsp_mosaic
Undefined function 'vl_usift' for input arguments of type 'single'.

Error in vl_dspsift (line 50)
frames = vl_usift(im);

Error in dsp_mosaic (line 68)
[f1, d1] = vl_dspsift(im1g, opt);
```

After Googling this error(I am new to MATLAB), I found a solution saying that maybe my function cannot be recognised by MATLAB, so I need to add the containing folder to the MATLAB search path, which I tried doing:

```
>> which vl_usift -all
'vl_usift' not found.

>> addpath ('/home/dsp_toolbox_v0.0.2/dsp_toolbox_v0.0.2/toolbox/sift/')
```

Howver, I get the same error when trying to run the code.
I can add the code if it helps, but I do need advice on how to proceed from here.

Thanks

Comment: It could also be saying that your input to 'vl_usift' is wrong, read the readme file on what your inputs are suppose to look

Comment: This looks like it's using VLFeat.  Did you compile the MEX wrappers to VLFeat before running the functions?

Comment: Yes, it is using VLFeat. The source code which I am testing is actaully setting VLFeat up before running the code. So I found that there was a problem with their setup file where they had commented a few lines of code and it is working now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a few hours of searching around, I finally came across the problem, there were a few lines commented in the setup file which I had to uncomment. Simple and frustrating.

Thanks!